# Results not returning rows where second parameter should match null

Tags: mysql, php

I'm trying to left join three tables using columns from the first and third tables as the filters. The second and third tables could have null values where I am trying to join. I want to be able to return all rows if I don't specify the second parameter (`:store_number`), but it only returns rows where the store_number is not null.

```
SELECT t1.host_name, t1.vcenter_name, t1.connection_state, t1.power_state, t2.cluster_name, t3.store_number, t3.district_number, t3.time_zone, t3.active
FROM host t1
LEFT JOIN cluster t2 ON t1.cluster_id = t2.cluster_id AND t1.vcenter_name = t2.vcenter_name
LEFT JOIN store t3 on t2.cluster_name IS NOT NULL AND t2.cluster_name = t3.store_number
WHERE t1.host_name LIKE :host_name AND t3.store_number LIKE :store_number
ORDER BY t1.host_name;
```

To clarify, not all hosts have clusters, and not all clusters associate to store numbers. I want to be able to return all rows even if I don't specify a store number in the parameter, but currently it only returns rows that have a store number that is not null. Passing to the parameter as %value%.

Here is what I am getting currently:

```
+-------------+---------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+--------+
| host_name   | vcenter_name  | connection_state | power_state | cluster_name | store_number | district_number | time_zone | active |
+-------------+---------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+--------+
| host1       | vcenter1      | Connected        | PoweredOn   | cluster1     | store1       | 1               | nonprod   | false  |
| host2       | vcenter1      | Connected        | PoweredOn   | cluster1     | store1       | 1               | nonprod   | false  |
| host1       | vcenter1      | Connected        | PoweredOn   | cluster2     | store2       | 2               | nonprod   | false  |
| host2       | vcenter1      | Connected        | PoweredOn   | cluster2     | store2       | 2               | nonprod   | false  |
+-------------+---------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+--------+
```

Here is what I would like to get:

```
+-------------+---------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+--------+
| host_name   | vcenter_name  | connection_state | power_state | cluster_name | store_number | district_number | time_zone | active |
+-------------+---------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+--------+
| host1       | vcenter1      | Connected        | PoweredOn   | cluster1     | store1       | 1               | nonprod   | false  |
| host2       | vcenter1      | Connected        | PoweredOn   | cluster1     | store1       | 1               | nonprod   | false  |
| host1       | vcenter1      | Connected        | PoweredOn   | cluster2     | store2       | 2               | nonprod   | false  |
| host2       | vcenter1      | Connected        | PoweredOn   | cluster2     | store2       | 2               | nonprod   | false  |
| host1       | vcenter2      | Connected        | PoweredOn   | NULL         | NULL         | NULL            | NULL      | NULL   |
| host1       | vcenter3      | Connected        | PoweredOn   | cluster3     | NULL         | NULL            | NULL      | NULL   |
| host2       | vcenter3      | Connected        | PoweredOn   | cluster3     | NULL         | NULL            | NULL      | NULL   |
+-------------+---------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: unclear what second parameter is and what 'it is not null means'. Include sample data and expected results.

Comment: Added additional information.

Comment: Put `t3.store_number LIKE :store_number` in your `JOIN ON` criteria rather than the `WHERE` criteria. Being in `WHERE` means the the store_number of null won't match the criteria.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! If you add that as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `t3.store_number LIKE :store_number` in your `JOIN ON` criteria rather than the `WHERE` criteria.

Being in `WHERE` means the the `store_number` of `NULL` won't match the criteria however being in a `LEFT JOIN`, `t3.*` are padded in the result when the `JOIN` criteria isn't met.